# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror

I have recently taken course on learning python and I have ran into this issue while trying to encode the data in my lesson. The action I typed in was

```
# Encoding categorical data

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
```

Once I enter this into the console, I get this message. `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
I have read responses towards similar questions but I am still at a lost here. Any tips would be of service to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know how you don't get a `NameError` for `X` unless this isn't your complete code

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused by your answer. I was following the prompt provided to me from the video courses I have been taking. I typed exactly what I saw from the demonstration video and received this instead of it being completed into the console.

Comment: Right, and I'm telling you that you definitely didn't include all of your code because you never define `X` in your code snippet, which would throw a `NameError`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LabelEncoder: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406720/labelencoder-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-str)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the column you are trying to encode has any missing or null values. Replacing the empty and null value rows with values worked for me.