# numpy unique() returns '<' not supported between float / str instances error - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a situation where I have an ID that's a concatenation of a three columns, two that are string datatypes and one that's an integer.

When I tried to pull,

```
print(np.unique(df['id']))
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Based on the searching I've done, it seems like this is an error that's a product of an inconsistent datatype in the dataframe's series, if that is the case - I still don't understand why this happens. When you're providing the unique values of a column, why isn't it possible to distinguish between 5333 vs. goatsforever200 as two unique values? Could be misunderstanding something in the process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LabelEncoder: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406720/labelencoder-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-str)

Comment: The error itself answers your question -

Fundamentally `numpy` should contain a homogenous datatype

Comment: Kind of! Thanks @ppwater

Comment: @Vaebhav - is it handled that way just for the sake of efficiency and consistency in numpy's functionality? Is this only specific to numpy?

Comment: **The point** of Numpy (which Pandas builds on top of) is to be able to represent multiple values that are *the same size in memory*, by allocating a *single chunk* of memory and putting all the values side-by-size. They need to be the same size because then the position of each element can be determined by simple arithmetic; if they could be varying sizes, then even if the sizes could be discovered on the fly, finding an element would require a search from the beginning, taking O(N) time for a simple indexing operation.