# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'method' While trying to apply an Encoder

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to apply an encoder for, to be specific LabelEncoder
using this code:

```
# Import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Instantiate LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()

# Iterate over all the values of each column and extract their dtypes
for col in cc_apps.columns.to_numpy():
    # Compare if the dtype is object
    if cc_apps[col].dtypes=='object':
    # Use LabelEncoder to do the numeric transformation
        cc_apps[col]=le.fit_transform(cc_apps[col])
```

unfortunately, it is giving me this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-082f4092a1b1> in <module>
     10     if cc_apps[col].dtypes=='object':
     11     # Use LabelEncoder to do the numeric transformation
---> 12         cc_apps[col]=le.fit_transform(cc_apps[col])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    110         """
    111         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 112         self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    113         return y
    114 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    221     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    222     if axis is None:
--> 223         return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    224     if not (-ar.ndim <= axis < ar.ndim):
    225         raise ValueError('Invalid axis kwarg specified for unique')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    278 
    279     if optional_indices:
--> 280         perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    281         aux = ar[perm]
    282     else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'method'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please forget about my previous answer and just change the last line of your for loop to this like: `cc_apps[col] = le.fit_transform(cc_apps[col].astype('str'))`, it will work.

Comment: @AdarshWase omg thank you so much, it did work, can you please explain to me what was wrong, because I did not really understand the type of error

Comment: also please add it as a solution so I can upvote it and mark it as correct

Comment: Label encoder is used to convert string/categorical columns into integers. You are getting the error because some of the rows in those object columns are not strings. So label encoder was confused to think of this sign '<' as operator or string. So, in the above solution, we are telling label encoder that, everything is string.

Comment: Your question is duplicate of this question [LabelEncoder: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406720/labelencoder-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-str).